jsonschema2pojo: Use Map for field
I know in jsonschema2pojo additionalProperties is java Map, but how can I declare one specific field also as Map? e.g. I want the following field config to be a Map.
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "config": {
        "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}

